# How to make a web crawler which visits the links obtained as search results on user queried information?

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

How to make a web crawler which visits the links obtained as search results on user queried information ? Say,if user gives some query about some subject,crawler must visits some of the top links only.Can anyone tell me how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) is probably your best bet.  It's free and designed to be interacted with programmatically.

However, if you need to interact with an obscure site, or require fine-grained control, I've written several crawlers with [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).  It's a little verbose, but definitely works.

Comment: Can you tell me how to install google custom search in netbeans in windows 7 and use it ?

Comment: Google provides a couple of short code samples ( http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/SampleProgram ) as well as download and setup instructions ( http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup ). Give those a try and let me know if you have problems.

Comment: Sample codes are not working.I found this code on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301608/connect-to-internet-google-custom-search-in-java-app-not-connecting but even this is not working(I have obtained an API key) Can you give me some code to test it ?